# Adding to a boolean array after sending an email - C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to add a boolean value to an array after sending an email. This way I know I've sent that Sensor ID email. I have deleted the bits where my email address and password would be for security and all! Here is my code:

```
public class Email
{
    //Create an array of bools that accepts nulls to check that an email has already been sent
    public bool[] ArrayEmailChecker = new bool[33];
    public static void MainEmail(DateTime timestamp, int SensorID)
    {
        var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
        {
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential("@gmail.com", ""),
            EnableSsl = true
        };
        client.Send("@gmail.com", "@gmail.com", "Alarm Alert!", ("There was an alarm today at: " + timestamp + " on Sensor: " + SensorID));
        Console.WriteLine("Sent");
        Console.ReadLine();
        //Create new instance of Email as this is a static method
        Email a = new Email();
        a.EmailChecker(SensorID);
    }

    public void EmailChecker(int SensorID)
    {
        ArrayEmailChecker[SensorID] = true;
    }
```

EDIT: Sorry forgot to add question!

I want to make it so every time this method is called, if the array has true in that particular sensor id, it won't call the method. So in another class, I have an if statement, checking the bool array. If there's false at that array[sensorid] then it will send an email. However every time my class checks, it seems to check against an array full of false values. The array doesn't seem to have changed.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: What is the issue? What is not working in your code?

Comment: You're already assigning a boolean value in the array. You're question is not making sense...

Comment: Flagged for closing as unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is either. However, any change to the ArrayEmailChecker array will be lost at the end of MainEmail when the newly created Email a goes out of scope. Did you mean to make ArrayEmailChecker static as well?

Comment: Sorry forgot question!! Added Edit!

Comment: Your edit still doesn't clear it up. You've explained exactly what you need (`I have an if statement, checking the bool array`).. What exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: @Rob When I run the code, the each time the array is checked, its only full of false values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry, but it has horrible design:).
Really, it is not the way it is supposed to be done.
Please, take it as constructive critique,
I will provide better solution here:

First, using arrays is very limited, and not as useful as it may seem.
For that kind job we have a dictionary and as static this kind stuff can be done concurrently, so I would use ConcurrentDictionary instead.

The second issue is, that the array was supposed to be static too.

So let's give it a try:

```
using System.Collections.Concurrent;


public static class Email
{
    private
    static
    readonly
    ConcurrentDictionary<int, bool> dict =
    new ConcurrentDictionary<int, bool>()
    ;

    public static bool TrySend(DateTime timestamp, int SensorID)
    {

        if (!dict.TryAdd(SensorID, true)) return false;

        var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
        {
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential("@gmail.com", ""),
            EnableSsl = true
        };

        client.Send("@gmail.com",
                    "@gmail.com",
                    "Alarm Alert!",
                    "There was an alarm today at: " +
                    timestamp  +
                    " on Sensor: " +
                    SensorID.ToString());

        Console.WriteLine("Sent SensorID: " + SensorID.ToString());
        return true;

    }

    public static void ClearSensorIDs()
    {
        dict.Clear();
    }
}
```

Now it will look into dictionary if there is already key SensorID, if not, it will send mail, and return back true. If exist, it returns false.

Added method ClearSensorIDs()...

Comment: Thing is, I was hoping to also use a button, which clears the array. Can this be done using the dictionary?

Comment: Sure, you can use the classic dictionary, but this way it is thread safe. All the code sending mail is concurrently safe, so why not to use it? For example, now it can be sent from any thread, or thread pool or fired as Task in the background... Anyway, I edited the answer providing clear method  for your button:).

Answer (score 0):

First, I would not expose ArrayEmailChecker as public. You could either provide an accessor method, such as

```
public static bool hasBeenSent(int sensorId);
```

or, just have MainEmail() check the flag.

However, you will also need to make ArrayEmailChecker static. When the Email value, a, you create in MainEmail() goes out of scope at the end of the method, the array goes away as well. A new one is created every time you call MainEmail().

Comment: I don't want to create a new one, how do I continue to use the old one?

Comment: As stated in my answer, make ArrayEmailChecker static. Then you don't need to create an EMail object in MainEmail(). And the EmailChecker() method can go away, too.

Comment: I'm not familiar with accessor method's could you maybe write out more code for me to understand?

Comment: All the "accessor" method does is return the value from the array for the given index. It allows you to make your array private.